# Windows 7 - Modify "advanced settings" tab of Device Manager from command line

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, command-line, network-adapter

I'm in a position where I need to enable Wake on LAN for roughly 50 machines. I don't want to have to go round every one and adjust the settings for it, but it's looking increasingly like I'll have to.

The network cards have a setting in the "advanced" tab of the adapter configuration panel that needs to be toggled from "off" to on to allow the wake on LAN to take place (I can't provide a screenshot from one of the machines with that card, but here's one of the same dialog from a virtual machine so you know which one I mean). [image]

Note that this setting **isn't** the same as the one on the *power management* tab.

I'd ideally like to change this configuration from a command line utility or script; could anyone point me to a location in the registry where device configuration is held, or a utility which could change these settings from Command Prompt?

Thus far, I've found [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) - a command line alternative/frontend to device manager, but I don't think it has the settings I need.

Cheers in advance :)

Comment: For the benefit of possible future readers whose problem *is* the setting on the power management tab: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11750071/886887

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by searching in the registry for the brand name and modifying a boolean key in the `HKEY_Local_Machine\system` branch for the network card.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this can be set using WMI.  Look at the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class for the details.  Also, you can use Powershell to manipulate WMI from the command-line.

Comment: nothing about WoL or custom settings on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx?

Answer (score 1):

Since jackweirdy did not provide the exact location of the keys he modified, they can be found here:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

You just need to simply determine the correct adapter....Vinith Menon has provided a great example of this here:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Configure-iSCSI-Network-81232a5e/view/Reviews

Simply scroll down to the relevant part of the script under the following comment:

> <#Below we set the advanced property #>